# Как добавить водяной знак к видеофайлу при сохранении в django

Tags: python, django, watermark

Я могу добавить водяной знак на видео, но как это применить к django модели.

**model.py**

```
class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title')
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photo/%Y/%m/%d')
    video_uploaded = models.FileField(upload_to='video/%Y/%m/%d',blank=True,null=True)
```

**views.py**

```
def add_video(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = VideoUploaderForm(
            data=request.POST,
            files=request.FILES,
        )
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            vid = request.FILES['video_uploaded']
            clip = VideoFileClip(vid.temporary_file_path())
            # watermark
            video = VideoFileClip(clip.filename)
            logo = (ImageClip('faiklogo.png')
                    .set_duration(video.duration)
                    .resize(height=50)
                    .margin(right=8, top=8, opacity=0)
                    .set_pos(("center", "bottom")))
            final_ = CompositeVideoClip([video, logo])
            final_.write_videofile('videwithwatermark.mp4')
            obj.save()
    else:
        form=VideoUploaderForm()
    return render(request, 'firstapp/add_video.html', {"foenter code hererm": form})
```

**form.py**

```
class VideoUploaderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Video
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0):

тебе необходимо итоговый файл закинуть в нужное поле

```
final_.write_videofile('videwithwatermark.mp4')
obj.save()
```

сменить на

```
final_.write_videofile('videwithwatermark.mp4')
obj.video_uploaded = filan_
obj.save()
```

Comment: 'CompositeVideoClip' object has no attribute '_committed'

Comment: не приходилось работать с VideoFileClip, но была задача с добавлением водяного знака в видео, вот данное решение:
os.system('ffmpeg -i {} -i watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay=30:30" {}'.format(path_input_file, path_output_file))
obj.video = path_output_file
obj.save()

но если всё же, хочешь продолжить своё решение, тут можешь глянуть ответ на схожую с твоей проблемой https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36610146/attributeerror-file-object-has-no-attribute-committed

Comment: не пойму как это работает. У меня пишет: ffmpeg: not found. Скинь пожалуйста полностью код куда это вставлять.

Comment: я полный код и скинул, гуглить нужно друг. тебе необходимо установить ffmpeg.
https://gist.github.com/bennylope/d5d6029fb63648582fed2367ae23cfd6